# plot the histogram of one coloumn data from a txt file

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I need to read data from a file which has only one column. Then plot the barred histogram of the data. However, by the following code the figure shows me only a line in zero and nothing more.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib

f= np.loadtxt('data Ties', unpack='False')

bins = np.linspace(0, 50, 100000)

plt.hist(f, bins, histtype='bar', rwidth=0.8)
plt.xlabel('Diameter')
plt.ylabel('Number of Chondrules')
plt.title('Distribution of chondules diameter')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This is the piece of data I have:

```
168000
199300
120900
216900
200800
137800
214200
174600
48200
126500
58700
149500
47500
5600
178500
25400
163000
182000
51900
66700
90300
210600
117800
164000
215200
170000
182000
38800
72700
161200
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to set proper number of bins, i.e.:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib

f= np.loadtxt('data', unpack='False')

# set bins' interval for your data
# You have following intervals: 
# 1st col is number of data elements in [0,10000);
# 2nd col is number of data elements in [10000, 20000); 
# ...
# last col is number of data elements in [100000, 200000]; 
bins = [0,10000,20000,50000,100000,200000] 

plt.hist(f, histtype='bar', bins = bins)
plt.xlabel('Diameter')
plt.ylabel('Number of Chondrules')
plt.title('Distribution of chondules diameter')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It worked. Thank you. Now I need to do something different. For each interval, I need to have the total number of objects that has those diameters ( for example, total number that have diameter between 10000 to 20000 and etc,.) I know that I have to do a loop and sum, but don't know how.

Comment: There is more elegant solution using bin of hist, look at the code above (you just need to set intervals for diameter).

Answer (score 0):

you got the arguments to `linspace` backwards - it is defined as `linspace(start, end, n)`, so you should write

```
bins = np.linspace(0, 100000, 50)
```